# Keeping an iPad keyboard up between inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

Right now I'm using a bit of jQuery to hide the iPad keyboard when an input loses focus.

```
    jQuery(function($) {
       $(document).on('touchend', function(e) {
          document.activeElement.blur();
       });
    });
```

However during a process like the checkout when a user clicks from input to input the keyboard disappears and the reappears every time the input is changed. Is there any way to change the above jquery code to where it only blurs the active element if the place on the document that is touched does NOT have an input type of text?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't tried this with iPad before, so I'm not sure that it will work, but you can check the type of `document.activeElement` to determine if it is a text or textarea field.  If it isn't, then perform your `blur()`.  The code would be like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('touchend', function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var currentElement = document.activeElement;

            if ($(currentElement).not("textarea, :text").length > 0) {
                currentElement.blur();
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

The `setTimeout` is needed to make sure that the focus has transferred to the next element, before checking what the current element is (doing it immediately, will return the `<body>` as the `activeElement`).

This general approach (i.e., identifying what type the current `activeElement` is) works in a desktop browser environment, and it ***SHOULD*** work on an iPad, but, like I said earlier, I've not had a chance to test it there, so this is more of a "possible solution" than an actual "answer", until you give it a try and se if it works for you.   :D

Comment: Sadly doing this removes it hiding the keyboard on input blur on an iPad. Not sure why, I blame Steve Jobs. Developing for this thing is a nightmare. But thanks for trying! =P

Comment: Well shoot . . . in theory, I would have thought that would have worked (based on my understanding of how your current code is behaving).  Oh well, I'm curious to see how this one gets solved . . . good luck!